# Flutter: inverted ClipOval

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to write a library to allow users to pan/zoom their profile picture.

In order to make it visual, I would like to stack their picture with an "inverted" ClipOval, to show the boundaries.

So far, this is the result I obtain:

[image]

This shows the boundaries but this is not user friendly and I would like to "invert" the ClipOval so that the center of the clip is "clear" and the outside is grayed out (something like a mask).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is the code I have so far (part of it comes from [flutter_zoomable_image](https://github.com/perlatus/flutter_zoomable_image)):

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class ImagePanner extends StatefulWidget {
  ImagePanner(this.image, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  /// The image to be panned
  final ImageProvider image;

  @override
  _ImagePannerState createState() => new _ImagePannerState();
}

class _ImagePannerState extends State<ImagePanner> {
  ImageStream _imageStream;
  ui.Image _image;
  double _zoom = 1.0;
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;
  double _scale = 16.0;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _resolveImage();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    _resolveImage();
    super.reassemble();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_image == null) {
      return new Container();
    }
    return new Container(
      width: double.INFINITY,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1.0,
                child: new Stack(
                  children: [
                    _child(),
                    new Opacity(
                      opacity: 0.5,
                      child: new ClipOval(
                        child: new Container(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }


  Widget _child() {
    Widget bloated = new CustomPaint(
      child: new Container(),
      painter: new _ImagePainter(
        image: _image,
        offset: _offset,
        zoom: _zoom / _scale,
      ),
    );

    bloated = new Stack(
      children: [
        new Container(
        ),
        bloated
      ],
    );

    return new Transform(
        transform: new Matrix4.diagonal3Values(_scale, _scale, _scale),
        child: bloated);
  }

  void _resolveImage() {
    _imageStream = widget.image.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
    _imageStream.addListener(_handleImageLoaded);
  }

  void _handleImageLoaded(ImageInfo info, bool synchronousCall) {
    print("image loaded: $info $synchronousCall");
    setState(() {
      _image = info.image;
    });
  }
}

class _ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  const _ImagePainter({this.image, this.offset, this.zoom});

  final ui.Image image;
  final Offset offset;
  final double zoom;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    paintImage(canvas: canvas, rect: offset & (size * zoom), image: image);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_ImagePainter old) {
    return old.image != image || old.offset != offset || old.zoom != zoom;
  }
}
```

The outcome I would like to obtain is the following so that users will directly see the boundaries and will be able to center, pan, zoom their profile picture INSIDE the oval.

[image]

(I made this via Photoshop, since I don't know how to achieve this with Flutter)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Not clear of what you are trying to achieve? Some visual ref of what you are trying to achieve might help!

Comment: Question edited to give additional details about the outcome I would like to obtain.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a couple other ways you could do this - you could simply draw an overlay in a CustomCanvas using a path that has a circle & rectangle, as all you really need is a rectangular semi-transparent rectangle with a hole in it. But you can also use a `CustomClipper` which gives you more flexibility in the future without having to draw stuff manually.

```
void main() {
  int i = 0;
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: new SafeArea(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("Tapped! ${i++}");
              },
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Container(
                    width: 400.0,
                    height: 300.0,
                    color: Colors.red.shade100,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new IgnorePointer(
              child: new ClipPath(
                clipper: new InvertedCircleClipper(),
                child: new Container(
                  color: new Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
}

class InvertedCircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return new Path()
      ..addOval(new Rect.fromCircle(
          center: new Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2),
          radius: size.width * 0.45))
      ..addRect(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

`IgnorePointer` is needed, or events won't be propagated through the semi-transparent part (assuming you need touch events).

How this works is that the `Path` used by clipPath is a circle in the middle (you need to adjust the size manually) with a rectangle taking up the entire size. `fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd` is important because it tells the path's fill should be between the circle and the rectangle.

If you wanted to use a customPainter instead, the path would be the same and you'd just draw it instead.

This all results in this:[image]

Comment: Spendid!  This is exactly what I was looking for...   Thanks so much.