# Flutter - How to get a semitransparent blurring layer with a hole with soft edges

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a screen for the coach mark. Idea is to blur and make darker everything except the region where is my icon located.

I could cut a circle with feather edges. But the icon on the background is also blurred.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new MaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter Demo',
       home: HomeScreen(),
     );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      _buildScaffold(),
      CustomPaint(
        child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: new ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2.0, sigmaY: 2.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[900].withOpacity(0.7)),
                ))),
        foregroundPainter: CoachMarksPainter(),
          ),
    ]);
  }

  Widget _buildScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hello"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              onPressed: () => print("press"),
              icon: new Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            ),
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                    image: new NetworkImage(
                        "http://www.mobileswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/640-Sunset-Beach-2-l.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover))));
  }
}

class CoachMarksPainter extends CustomPainter {
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print("Paint size=$size canvas=${canvas.getSaveCount()}");
    canvas.save();

    Path path = Path()
      ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(287.0, 52.0), radius: 25.0))
      ..addRect(new Rect.fromLTWH(
          -10.0, -10.0, size.width + 20.0, size.height + 20.0))
      //to have rect a bit larger than screen, so blurred edges won't be seen
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;

    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.dstOut
      ..color = Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4)
      ..maskFilter = new MaskFilter.blur(
          BlurStyle.normal, 2.0); //BoxShadow.convertRadiusToSigma(25.0)

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CoachMarksPainter oldDelegate) => false;
  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(CoachMarksPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[blurred background with a highlighted icon in a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjhvj.png)

Is it possible to use ImageFilter.blur for Canvas? I use MaskFilter, but it does not blur canvas as much as ImageFilter for BackdropFilter widget.
Ideally, I want to get a semitransparent blurring layer with a hole with soft edges.

P.S. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter) but I need to invert it.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Hi! I saw your answer in similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374893/flutter-inverted-clipoval. I hope you can help me with this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Marica Hopefully this is doing what you want.

[image: screen capture]

https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/76043f8f3fc4a8b20fc24c5a6f22b0a0

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Coach Mark Demo',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffold = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<CoachMarkState> _calendarMark = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffold,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CoachMark(
            key: _calendarMark,
            id: 'calendar_mark',
            text: 'Tap here to use the Calendar!',
            child: GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () => _calendarMark.currentState.show(),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => print('calendar'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: 'reset',
                  child: Text('Reset'),
                ),
              ];
            },
            onSelected: (String value) {
              if (value == 'reset') {
                _calendarMark.currentState.reset();
                _scaffold.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Hot-restart the app to see the coach-mark again.'),
                ));
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("http://www.mobileswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/640-Sunset-Beach-2-l.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CoachMark extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoachMark({
    Key key,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String id;
  final String text;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  CoachMarkState createState() => CoachMarkState();
}

typedef CoachMarkRect = Rect Function();

class CoachMarkState extends State<CoachMark> {
  _CoachMarkRoute _route;

  String get _key => 'mark_${widget.id}';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    test().then((bool seen) {
      if (seen == false) {
        show();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CoachMark oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _rebuild();
  }

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    _rebuild();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    dismiss();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _rebuild();
    return widget.child;
  }

  void show() {
    if (_route == null) {
      _route = _CoachMarkRoute(
        rect: () {
          final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          return box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size;
        },
        text: widget.text,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        onPop: () {
          _route = null;
          mark();
        },
      );
      Navigator.of(context).push(_route);
    }
  }

  void _rebuild() {
    if (_route != null) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _route.changedExternalState();
      });
    }
  }

  void dismiss() {
    if (_route != null) {
      _route.dispose();
      _route = null;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> test() async {
    return (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getBool(_key) ?? false;
  }

  void mark() async {
    (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).setBool(_key, true);
  }

  void reset() async {
    (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).remove(_key);
  }
}

class _CoachMarkRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  _CoachMarkRoute({
    @required this.rect,
    @required this.text,
    this.padding,
    this.onPop,
    this.shadow = const BoxShadow(color: const Color(0xB2212121), blurRadius: 8.0),
    this.maintainState = true,
    this.transitionDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 450),
    RouteSettings settings,
  }) : super(settings: settings);

  final CoachMarkRect rect;
  final String text;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final BoxShadow shadow;
  final VoidCallback onPop;

  @override
  final bool maintainState;

  @override
  final Duration transitionDuration;

  @override
  bool didPop(T result) {
    onPop();
    return super.didPop(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    Rect position = rect();
    if (padding != null) {
      position = padding.inflateRect(position);
    }
    position = Rect.fromCircle(center: position.center, radius: position.longestSide * 0.5);
    final clipper = _CoachMarkClipper(position);
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTapDown: (d) => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child: IgnorePointer(
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipPath(
                  clipper: clipper,
                  child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2.0, sigmaY: 2.0),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                CustomPaint(
                  child: SizedBox.expand(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(text,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  painter: _CoachMarkPainter(
                    rect: position,
                    shadow: shadow,
                    clipper: clipper,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;
}

class _CoachMarkClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final Rect rect;

  _CoachMarkClipper(this.rect);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, Path()..addRect(Offset.zero & size), Path()..addOval(rect));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(_CoachMarkClipper old) => rect != old.rect;
}

class _CoachMarkPainter extends CustomPainter {
  _CoachMarkPainter({
    @required this.rect,
    @required this.shadow,
    this.clipper,
  });

  final Rect rect;
  final BoxShadow shadow;
  final _CoachMarkClipper clipper;

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final circle = rect.inflate(shadow.spreadRadius);
    canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());
    canvas.drawColor(shadow.color, BlendMode.dstATop);
    canvas.drawCircle(circle.center, circle.longestSide * 0.5, shadow.toPaint()..blendMode = BlendMode.clear);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_CoachMarkPainter old) => old.rect != rect;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(_CoachMarkPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Simon, thanks a lot!
A few questions: 
1) We need to wrap icon to `CoachMark` in order to get it position. I guess it is also possible just pass position to `_CoachMarkRoute` and push it from my screen when conditions are pass. And I need somehow to get know position of icon (maybe using after layout). But your solution is more elegant and flexible.
2) Why do you need a `_route` variable in `CoachMarkState`? I don't see where it is assigned a value.
3) What does `_route.changedExternalState();` do?

Comment: 1) Yes you can just pass the rect to the route, or just pass the context of any Widget.
2) Ah, that explains why a bug I had exists. I'll update the code.
3) The idea is to have it update the rect when the widget changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. It seems that what you want would be achievable by using 3 layers in a stack. Lowest is your background, second is the darker frosted blur and put your icon on top.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I start with icon. But it can be another part of UI in the scaffold. I don't want to draw it again. I don't know exact position of all elements. So it should be 2 layers - scaffold on background and dark frosted blur with hole.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon's answer is absolutely right. I tried and it really works. It's kind of like the Android's Xfermode or BlendMode. But to be honest, Simon's code is quite a lot, and it took me a bunch of time to get to understand it. To help others easily understand the code, may I present the simpler version?

```dart
class MyOverlayPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Paint brush = Paint()
    ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear;

  @override bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  @override void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());
    canvas.drawColor(Colors.black54, BlendMode.dstATop);  // translucent bg
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(150, 150), 75, brush);
    canvas.restore();
  }
}
```

And this will work as well.