# Black screen with circle in the middle

Tags: flutter, dart, styling

Hi I am trying to create a screen that is completely black, except of a circle in the middle.
I wrote some code that creates the black screen:

```
       Stack(
         ...
          Positioned.fill(
                child: Container(
                       color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
               )
          )
     )
```

But the problem that I am facing is that I don't know how to punch a round hole into the screen so that so that it shows what is behind it in the stack.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Check out [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49396544/3925977), I think it's exactly what you want.

Comment: @MickaelHrndz Yes I have seen that but I did not understand the part with the 'InvertedCircleClipper' class. The actual question then is, if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **CircleAvatar** to draw Circles! 
Change the `radius:` property to your desired size, a lot easier than `Containers()`, or `FloatingActionButtons()`

```
Container(
  color: Colors.black,
  Center(
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      radius: 20,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes but it sill doesn't show the content that is behind it, considering that there is something, a layer beneath it, because of `Stack`

Comment: Reduce the opacity of the color, or make it totally transparent using `Color(0x00000000)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("BackGround Text", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                  radius: 100,
                ),
              ],
            )));
```

Comment: This is not really what I meant, the hole should be see-through so that you can see the content, **that is behind**, it in the stack.

Comment: @Mo711: Edited the answer, have  a look